# Abnormalities in results L-LDA

Tags: machine-learning, classification

For my research I am using Labelled Latent Dirichlet Allocation (L-LDA) on Reuters-21578 ModApte split dataset. In this dataset the news stories have a title and a body. To test the effect of L-LDA, I apply it in on all three combinations, thus **Title**, **Body** and **Title&Body**. I compare my results with Joachims (1998) where they report his results of the top10 categories by using Break-even performance and Micro-average performance over all 90 categories.

Now, LDA is said to work very well on short pieces of text. Yet, when I apply L-LDA on the dataset, the Micro-average performance over all 90 categories gives the following results:

```
Title: 95.68%
Body: 93.01%
Title&Body: 91.88%
```

This indeed shows that L-LDA performas better on short text (**Title**). However, when I look at the Break-even performances of the top10 categories, 3 out of 10 times **Title&Body** performs best and 6 out of 10 times **Title**.

Also, when comparing **Body** and **Title&Body**, we see **Title&Body** is 6 out of 10 times better than **Body**.

My question now is, how is it possible that, even though **Title&Body** has more features, it scores better than **Body** when applying L-LDA?